# How to select web-component tags from a html string

Tags: javascript, regex, element

I am trying to select the costume tags from a string in JS.

```
<my-elem data-val="abc" />
<div style="color:red">hi</div>
<elem data-val="abc" />
<my-elem2>bar</my-elem2>
<br/>
```

to return `["<my-elem data-val="abc" />","<my-elem2>"]`

I was trying something like
`*<[a-z]-[a-z] */>` but an bad at the regx :(

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code I got working

```
var customTagMatch = /<\s*[a-z]+-[a-z][^>]*>/g

`<my-elem data-val="abc" />
<div style="color:red">hi</div>
<elem data-val="abc" />
<my-elem2>bar</my-elem2>
<br/>`.match(customTagMatch)
```

outputs

```
["<my-elem data-val="abc" />", "<my-elem2>"]
```

Hope this helps someone